Does a Chinese citizen need transit visa for connecting flight in Paris
I will fly from MRU to Boston via connecting flight in Paris. Do I need a transit visa?

Usually not, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area
